# What is frank dehydration?

Tags: terminology, dehydration

On Wikipedia article about [Urine specific gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urine_specific_gravity) we can read:

> A specific gravity greater than 1.035 is consistent with **frank dehydration**.

What is *frank dehydration*? How it is different than regular dehydration?

Comment: A higher specific gravity means a higher concentration of salt. And a lower concentration of water. You can now think about reasons why the human body looses lots of water, the most likely is heat and not enough resupply of water. The Wikipedia article also states that the normal specific density is between 1.000 and 1.030, so you are beyond the normal range.

Comment: What about _frank_ word, it's any special wording to indicate some kind of type of dehydration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Frank dehydration" is not really a regular medical term. You can suspect this by using Google search with "frank dehydration" in quotes and [site:gov](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=site%3Agov%20%22frank%20dehydration%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22frank%20dehydration%22&gs_l=hp.12...1209.14004.0.19437.28.28.0.0.0.0.409.3387.1j20j4-1.22.0....0...1c.1.55.hp..21.7.1035.TGsbGVv3Mmg) (only 3 websites showing up) and [site:edu](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&q=site%3Aedu%20%22frank%20dehydration%22&oq=site%3Aedu%20%22frank%20dehydration%22&gs_l=serp.3...52488.53656.0.53985.6.6.0.0.0.0.23.68.6.6.0....0...1c.1.55.serp..6.0.0.cu6zFhhPgHY) (2 websites) operators.

The term "frank dehydration" as an informal term can refer to "obvious," "actual," "test-confirmed" dehydration as opposed to feeling dehydrated or thirsty.

Tests to confirm dehydration include a combination of the body exam (dry mouth, prolonged skin turgor, decreased body weight), urine tests (dark urine, increased urine specific gravity, decreased urination frequency and 24-hour urine volume) and blood tests (increased sodium levels - hypernatremia).